# Excel columns are stored as text but they're numeric in the database. Need most of them as "Numeric with no decimals" in the excel sheet. Using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, postgresql, epplus

I am working on a report that outputs an excel file.  It has 7 tabs/worksheets that the user can choose between.  I got the first 5 to format correctly.

But for some reason one of the columns in the 6th worksheet and all the columns in the 7th worksheet don't work and show up as text in the excel cells.  For most of them that aren't working(They're showing up as text in the excel cells) I need them formatted as `Numeric with no decimals.`

Below is how I'm doing the formatting for some of the stuff that worked previously. Keep in mind this worked for the previous 5 worksheets:

`ws.Columns[11].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#####0.0000"; ws.Columns[13].Style.Numberformat.Format = "###,###"; ws.Columns[20].Style.Numberformat.Format = "$###,###,##0.00;($###,###,##0.00)"`

I think my issue is when the data in the database is numeric and keeping it numeric in the excel sheet isn't working.  Although I just checked and I've dealt with numeric types from the database that format correctly though..  Not sure why it's not working..  What am I missing here folks?

Comment: I think we need more details about how the Excel file is populated from your db.

Comment: Post the code that creates the Excel file. Excel has numeric and date types and the *actual* values remain numbers or dates, no matter how they're displayed for formatting. If you use `LoadFromCollection` or `LoadFromDataReader` the values will be strongly typed

Comment: The format for column 13 doesn't have a decimal place while columns 11 & 20 do.